# show ALL latest posts with archive.php on example.com/latest

Tags: url-rewriting, archives, rewrite-rules, archive-template

I want to make a rewrite-rule for latest posts `example.com/latest` via `rewrite_rules_array`-filterhook and display the posts with `archive.php`.

Usually this is what `example.com/index.php` does, I guess? But I use my themes `index.php` for a custom index page.

`index.php?category_name=technik` successfully gets output from `archive.php`, but how can I get the output from `archive.php` with no additional filtering whatsoever?

```
add_filter("rewrite_rules_array", function($rules) {
    $newRules = array();

    // works as expected
    $newRules['fliegen/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?category_name=fliegen&filter=$matches[1]';

    // output generated by themes index.php
    $newRules['latest'] = 'index.php';

    // also tried, but still output by themes index.php
    $newRules['latest2'] = 'archive.php';
    $newRules['latest3'] = 'wp-content/themes/mytheme/archive.php';

    // Return merged rules
    return array_merge($newRules, $rules);
});
```

I found a workaround, which is rather ugly– just list all categories ..

```
index.php?category_name=technik,fliegen,foo,bar
```

But posts without category still won't be showed. Open for suggestions! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All internal rules must point to `index.php`. This isn't your theme's `index.php` file, this is the main core WordPress bootstrap file.

Rewrite rules set query vars, query vars get parsed into queries, those queries have template files associated with them depending on type. Internal rewrite rules never point directly to theme files. If you want to modify the template for a query, use a [template filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#filter-hierarchy).

So for your example, first we add a query var to distinguish this request from others:

```
function wpd_query_vars( $vars ){
    $vars[] = 'wpd_template';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpd_query_vars' );
```

Next we add a rule. We use `add_rewrite_rule` here. If we're just adding to and not modifying the array of rules, it's simpler to use this rather than `rewrite_rules_array`:

```
function wpd_add_rewrite(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'latest/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=post&wpd_template=true',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_add_rewrite' );
```

Note that we set our custom query var here, so we can detect it in the next step, the template filter. We also set simple `post_type=post` to get the default latest posts ordered by date.

And last, the filter to force the `archive.php` file for this request if the `wpd_template` var is present:

```
function wpd_home_template( $template ){
    global $wp_query;
    if( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['wpd_template'] ) ){
        return locate_template( 'archive.php', false );
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'home_template', 'wpd_home_template' );
```

Comment: Bam! I luv the internez– Unsung hero indeed <3 – Not only did you solve my issue, but lead me to TWO new revelations in how wordpress handles things; `rewrite_rules_array` only to core index.php and `template filter`  (Man, one really has to fight hard for these revelations..)

Comment: But back to topic: 1) This solution works, but still feels like a workaround; I'm just curious for why there is no native way to show ALL posts via archive.php – I don't think this is an edge usecase, or is it? 2) Could you elaborate on why chose `add_rewrite_rule()` over `rewrite_rules_array`-hook? I asked another question regarding rewrite-rules; I'd really appreciate your help there aswell: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/286928/rewrite-rule-confusion-how-to-inspect-debug

Comment: 3) Why wouldn't the posts be ordered by date if we don't set `post_type=post` in our rewrite rule?

Comment: 4) My docs (Dash App for Mac) don't know the `home_template` hook; how is one supposed to find out what to use, when not even the main docs don't show them.. I found it mentioned here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks_2.0.x – So what exactly does it do? And why don't we use `archive_template` filter?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a rewrite rule at all. You can simply alter the main query when you're on `archive.php`, like so:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'show_all_posts' );

function show_all_posts( $query ) {

    if( ! is_admin() && is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() {
        $query->set( 'post_status', 'publish' );  
    }

}
```

The above will work on all archive pages. If you only want it to work on the "Latest" page, change it as follows:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'show_all_posts' );

function show_all_posts( $query ) {

    if( ! is_admin() && is_page( 'latest' ) && $query->is_main_query() {
        $query->set( 'post_status', 'publish' );  
    }

}
```

If you don't have a "Latest" page, you could create one and leave it blank. Then, you can create a template called `latest.php` and assign it to the "Latest" page. In `latest.php`, just put this:

```
get_template_part( 'archive' );
```

and it will look exactly like your `archive.php` template.

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to create a blank page, then maybe you can create a 'Latest' category, and assign a template to that category page? Not much fiddling a client can do with a category I guess... This doesn't mean you would have to add all posts to the 'Latest' category; you would just still have to use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query so that it doesn't return the posts in the 'Latest' category only (which is empty really), but those in all categories (so, all the existing posts).

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'show_all_posts' );

function show_all_posts( $query ) {

    if( ! is_admin() && is_category( 'latest' ) && $query->is_main_query() {
        $query->set( 'post_status', 'publish' );  
        $query->set( 'category__in', $all_posts );  
    }

}
```

Notice how I change `is_page( 'latest' )` to `is_category( 'latest' )`. Also, the `$all_posts` variable will have to be an array containing the IDs of all of your categories. Not sure how you can do that, but I guess that must be fairly easy to accomplish.

I've never tested this though, it's just an idea. Hope it helps!

Comment: Interesting; But I would rather not create a blank page with custom template for it– The client has to edit pages; Latest is nothing the he should be able to fiddle around with.